# How to make Note 8 screen dimmer?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-8

The screen is still way to bright at it's dimmest setting at night. I don't want to use an app that places a filter with an opacity setting over the screen because it just makes the screen look crappy and just makes everything bright grey instead of actually lowering brightness very much.

Is it possible?

Comment: Not sure what that means. Can you point me in the right direction so I can learn more?

Comment: Sorry, for being cryptic. Gravity Box Xposed module is a very powerful tool and screen dimmer is an small portion and it works well. You can also integrate that with automation. There are other rooted tools but I found this best

Answer (score 1):

I have an earlier Samsung phone which can use [Llama](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kebab.Llama), an automation tool which sets profiles that activate upon entry/exit to known areas, like Wifi seen/not seen. Your phone can most likely use it or a similar automation tool to do the same.

In Llama, I have set up a profile for nighttime (time range), plus my specific area, to lower volume and screen dim. Llama's settings allow screen dimming down to as little as 1% from its selector, with about a dozen settings to choose from.

Disclaimer: I am not the developer of Llama, just a satisifed user for many years.

Comment: Upvoted because I really like the application. Unfortunately though Llama's lowest setting for brightness is the same as me turning the brightness down all the way the normal way.

Answer (score 0):

So far the best thing that I've found to help is just setting the background to black (and not black onyx or any other "mostly" black background). Obviously this doesn't help in applications, but the main source of light that I didn't like was from the home screen so this helped a little.